# AngularJS why I'm getting this Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop and How to Fix it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm writing a directive in D3 and Angular. I'm not sure why I keep getting the `Infinite $digest loop` error as I don't see any reassignments for `newValue`. Functionality works just fine but the annoying errors in browser makes me want to dig into it.

Here is the code of directive:

```
scope.$watch('mode', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        scope.triggerAnimation();
    }
});

scope.triggerAnimation = function() {
    var speed = 4;
    var start = Date.now();

    if (scope.mode === null) {
        d3.timer(function() {
            var angle = (Date.now() - start) * speed;
            var transform = function(d, i) { return "rotate(" + angle / 50 + "," + centerX + "," + centerY + ")"; };

            svg.selectAll(".sidenode, .sidenodeedge").attr("transform", transform);
            if (scope.mode == null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        scope.mode = 1;
    } else {
        scope.mode = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have a the following:

```
scope.$watch('mode', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        scope.triggerAnimation();
    }
});
```

and then you you run the function, which always will change the `scope.mode` value

```
scope.triggerAnimation = function() {
    ...
    if (scope.mode === null) {
        // some code here
        scope.mode = 1;
    } else {
        scope.mode = null;
    }
}
```

It looks like it always will change `scope.mode` value from `null` to `1`. And each time will rise `$digest` call. And again...and again...

Comment: Now I understand why digest loop is called again and again. Thanks first! However, I do need to change the `mode` value in that `if else` loop. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: First: do you need to use $watch for your task? Is it impossible to solve without using this function? Because, it's not recommended to use it and suggested to avoid it if possible.
Second: do you need to watch (by $watch) and change in `if else` the same variable?

Comment: 1 $watch is not a must... I can use other options but I need to monitor if that value is change or not ... 2. I do need change the same variables

Comment: There should be an exit criteria in triggerAnimation function, in which it does not change the mode value.

Comment: Agree with @MadhuRanjan - your animations shouldn't run always. and if you need to run it in some interval, then you should use something different instead of `$watch` (e.g. `$timeout`)

Comment: @MadhuRanjan TriggerAnimation is a self-explained function. `if(scope.mode == null) {return true;} ` This is when the animation is stopped.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo Actually ·if(scope.mode == null) {return true;}· this line of code is where to stop the animation - as long as the function returns true, it will stop the animation. Any thoughts?

Comment: @catlovespurple - Can you share you code when you start/stop the animation? Because I think that what you want to do can be done by simple calling start/stop functions (without any watchers)

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo I don't have that code, it's all controlled by the value of `mode` variable now...  Maybe we can think of a way to add a start button, and change that value accordingly?  do note that value of mode is the trigger now.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo BTW, this is the reference I'm taking - it's written in JS and I used Angular...http://bl.ocks.org/atul-github/f3dc48348b0dfeb79618

Comment: @catlovespurple i am not very much familiar with d3, but it seems d3.timer  will call the function after some time.. and also i dont see any time being passed in d3.timer. if you think of JavaScript execution stack , mode is changed before it goes inside d3 call back function and the watch function also triggers a callback on change of mode. Try adding some console log to see what is the value inside your d3 timer call back.. and if it triggers at all..